# how can I find out what javascript objects are in use on a page? (digging through a webpack bundle)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to manipulate a javascript object that is created by another script on the page. This script is a fairly large webpack bundle, and all the variable names that get used in this bundle do not seem to actually be in use on the web page – as far as I can see by running `console.log(varname)` on them, which always returns `undefined`.

I tried going through the options offered when starting to feed `console.log` with a name, but nothing came up that looked too promising (I tried some options but found nothing helpful).

Some background information on what I am trying to do: I am working with [Grav](https://getgrav.org/), a flat file CMS, which in its Admin plugin uses a [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) editor, among many other scripts. All the scripts are [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) bundled into [admin.js](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-admin/blob/develop/themes/grav/js/admin.min.js) and [vendor.js](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-admin/blob/develop/themes/grav/js/vendor.min.js) (CodeMirror seems to be contained in the latter). I would like to use a CodeMirror addon and some different CodeMirror options, all of which is easy to do with standalone CodeMirror code – but I can't figure out how to get to the CodeMirror object in Grav Admin.

Your ideas are **much** appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can try printing `window` in the console - and see all variables in the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, anything using webpack is likely to be only using variables scoped to the modules inside it. Modules are designed to they *don't* shove variables into the global scope (where they might clash with variables from other scripts).

It you want to change the way the script works, get the source code for it, edit it, then compile it with webpack again.